# What is the probability of wining in a recursive situation?

Tags: probability

Problem:You and your opponent each roll a fair $4$-sided die. Suppose the outcomes of the rolls are a and b respectively. If $a ≥ b + 2$ then you win, if $a < b$ then you lose. Otherwise, the game is repeated from the start. Compute the probability that you win.

The probability of win in the first round game is $3/16$, but I don't know how to do next. It seems there can be infinite round when the game is not decided. How can I calculate the wining probability in a recursive question?

Comment: Compute the probability of losing in the first round.  Then, assume, without loss of generality, that the game is decided by exactly one round.  That is, if the game is decided by exactly $~(n)~$ rounds, then the first $~(n-1)~$ rounds may be ignored.  See also [this article on conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Comment: There are three outcomes to a round.  Either you win, or you lose, or you reset.  If you reset, your probability of winning is the same as it was at the start.  that lets the recursion go through.

Comment: Oh I see, I only need to consider the winning probability in nth round. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint, suppose the probability of $A$ winning is $a$, probability of $B$ winning is $b$, and probability of neither (call it a draw) is $c$.  Then $A$ wins on the $n$-th round if and only if there is a draw for the first $n-1$ rounds and then $A$ wins on the $n$-th, with probability $c^{n-1}a$.

Comment: The event that the game goes infinitely many rounds without being decided has probability $0$, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} c^n = 0$ when $0 \le c < 1$.  The ratio of the winning probabilities of you and your opponent is the same as the ratio of those on any given round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the following hold for each round...

- Probability of Win = $w$
- Probability of Draw = $d$
- Probability of loss = $l$

So $w+d+l=1$

if $P(n)$ is the probability of winning on the $n^{th}$ round then ...

$$ P = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}wd^{n-1}$$
this can be evaulated as a geometric series...
$$ = w\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}d^n = \frac w{1-d}= \frac w{w+l}$$

So the total win probability is the probability of winning in any round GIVEN THAT THE GAME IS DECIDED on that round

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an infinite sum: Call the probability of win draw or lose in one round w, d and l. Let W be the probability in the game. You win the game if you win the round, or you draw in the round and win the game. So

```
W = w + d * W
```

or

```
W * (1-d) = w
```

or

```
W = w / (1-d)
```

You can see that you cannot calculate W from w alone. d could be anything from 0 to 1-w so W could be anything from w to 1 depending on d and l. If the game is symmetrical so that w = l then W = L = 0.5 independent of w = l.